# How do you find and replace characters with app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wanting to find every instance of this character (â€™) in a specific Google sheet named "SF" and remove it from the sheet.

What I have thus far is the ability to remove it from a specific range within that sheet (i.e. J:J) but would like that range to be (A:AT)

Please advise on where my function is wrong in processing for a range.

```html
function CleanInputs() {
  var sf = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SF");
  var range = sf.getRange("J:J");

  //Finds and replace character encoding issues from Screamingfrog 
  range.setValues(range.getValues().map(function(row) {
  return [row[0].replace(/â€™/, "")];
}));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) and [replaceAllWith](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceAllWith(String)):

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "SF";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sh.createTextFinder("â€™").replaceAllWith("");
}
```